# How to put multiple lines of text into a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I have something like this:

[image]

and i would like to have something like this:

[image]

Comment: simply add `Environment.NewLine` to your string where you want the breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Environment.NewLine` as suggested by Jonesopolis.
See the [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.100).aspx), the caracters for the new line depend on the system you are targeting. Let the .NET framework know what a new line is.

You can use it like that

```
string str = String.Format("this text{0}is on three{0}lines", Environment.NewLine);
```

Or, if you're using the last version of C# (can be less readable if you have a lot of new lines) :

```
string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
string str = $"this text is{newLine}on three{newLine}lines";
```

Answer (score 3):

Insert "\r\n" where ever you want to add line

```
"It's Felix Birthday\r\nIt's DesBirthday\r\nIt's Fffffffs Birthday!"
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated before`\r\n` is a good use to insert new lines. Alternatively (and my personal choice) is to use `Environment.NewLine` which effectively does the same thing. However this is based on the `Enviroment` and therefore should be cross environment compatible (all-be-it no other WPF environment exists).

Something like

```
string message = string.Format("It's Felix Birthday{0}It's DesBirthday{0}It's Fffffffs Birthday!", Environment.NewLine);
```

Really this will just produce the same result as entering in the `\r\n` but also makes it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageBox.Show("It's Felix Birthday\nIt's DesBirthday\nIt's Fffffffs Birthday!");
```

> Just put "\n" where you want to new line

Answer (score -1):

By using TextWrapping, you will be able to use multiline textbox.
TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxLines="2" Width="150"

Comment: While this might allow multiple lines, the user has no control over what text goes on a new line (Unless they pad with extra whitespace).